# Driver for Vodafone USB dongle K3570-z

Tags: usb-modem

Kindly send me the driver for Vodafone USB dongle K3570-z or any other necessary steps for installing Vodafone USB dongle K3570-z for eduubuntu.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: "Kindly send me the driver" We cannot upload files on this website.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your problem is solved by now. I have just bought a Vodafone USB Stick K3773 and after a bit of fiddling managed to install it under Kubunbtu 12.04:

1. mount the USB stick (e.g., this can be done by clicking on the USB device notifier and opening the Vodafone by Doplhin)

   1. copy the contents of the linux_mbb directory into a temporary directory of yours (anywhere is fine), for instance

`xian$ mkdir QuickStart;cp /media/QuickStart\ 3.7/linux_mbb_install/* QuickStart/.`

1. get to this directory and change the right for the install file:

   `xian$ cd QuickStart; chmod +x install`
2. run install as root:

   `xian$ ./install`
3. accept to remove the install file from the USB stick when asked if so.

The connection is then recognized as wired connection 2 on my network at each new connection (and the USB stick is not mounted any longer).